# Limit involving $x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ term

Tags: calculus, limits

I have $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \left(x + x\sin(\frac{1}{x})\right) = 0$.

My proof is that $\forall\, x\in\mathbb{R}^*\,, \text{we have}  -1 \leq \sin(\frac{1}{x}) \leq 1$ $\implies -x \leq x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) \leq x$.

Hence $ \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(-x+x\right) \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow0} \left(x + x\sin(\frac{1}{x})\right) \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(x+x\right)$ $\implies$ $0 \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow0} \left(x + x\sin(\frac{1}{x})\right) \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(2x\right)$.

And since $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \left(2x\right) = 0$. Then, $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \left(x + x\sin(\frac{1}{x})\right) = 0$.

My question: is my proof correct?

If yes, do you have another more intelligent proof that can lead to the same result?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: You have a good idea about using the squeeze theorem. You just need to be more careful, your inequality will not work for negative $x$ so maybe just say that $-|x| \le x\sin \frac{1}{x} \le |x|$

Comment: @Vasili Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct proof, but probably need absolute values. Can be made more rigorous using a $\delta -\epsilon $ argument.

By definition of a limit, $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=L \iff \forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0 , |x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

In this case $L=0$ so we need to guarantee $|x\sin (1/x)|<\epsilon$

$|x\sin (1/x)|<|x|$ since $\sin $ is bounded above by $1$.

So if $|x|<\epsilon$, it follows $|x\sin(1/x)|<\epsilon$. This tells us if $\delta = \epsilon$ we satisfy the formal definition of a limit.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is correct. Since you show
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x\sin \left(\frac1x\right)=0$$
the fact that you have a first summand $x$ is actually not relevant.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer!